# Unable to connect Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P6200 in debugging mode

Tags: android, debugging, samsung-mobile

I bought a new Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P6200 for developing android application. When I connect my tablet device to the system(with Ubuntu 11.04 OS and with Eclipse ), it doesn't recognize debugging mode even I enable debugging mode in the settings. It automatically connects to MTP-mode(Media Transfer Protocol), and I cannot view the folders in the sdcard. Someone please help me to connect my device in debugging mode.

Comment: Its a device bug :( I changed my device

Answer (score 1):

Have you try restarting the adb server?
Open a Terminal, go to your android-sdk/platform-tools folder and execute:

```
./adb kill-server
```

then start it again with root access

```
sudo ./adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember I faced this problem before. You should try to following:

- Check if you have install driver for it(in Help/Software Updates of eclispe)
- Also, `sudo ./adb kill-server` `sudo ./adb start-server` check if it connected by sudo ./adb devices
- Try with other USB port.

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you used Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P6200 ??

Comment: Is that the first Samsung tablet? those helped me

Comment: Do you have MacOS or Win? Does it recognize your tablet? Make sure you have install driver for it. Also ,some suggest to install Samsung Kies to get drivers

Comment: I have Ubuntu 11.04 OS. Do I have to install any driver for linux Ubuntu?? I think no need of installing driver for linux.

Comment: Can you try this "If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs, below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:"   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: Yes I followed the step given in the link you mentioned,but still it is not connecting.